# Add class or data-attribute to product options

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I need to add some additional information in product options. I have already added a new field:

[image]

And also have already created plugin for changing option type `select.php`.

How can I get the value of this field and add it to select option and radio input as class or data-attribute? This is what I want to get as a result:

```
<select name="" id="select_17" class=" required product-custom-option admin__control-select" title="" data-selector="" aria-required="true">
<option value="29" price="0" data-field="test">Value 1 </option>
<option value="29" price="0" data-field="other">Value 2 </option>
</select>
```

and

```
<div class="control">
    <div class="options-list nested" id="options-16-list">
        <div class="field choice admin__field admin__field-option required">
            <input data-field="test" class="radio admin__control-radio test  required product-custom-option" name="options[16]" id="options_16_2" value="28" data-selector="options[16]" price="2" aria-required="true" type="radio"><label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_16_2"><span>Value</span> <span class="price-notice">+ <span class="price-container tax weee"><span data-price-amount="2" data-price-type="" class="price-wrapper ">$2.00</span></span></span></label>
        </div>
    </div><span id="options-16-container"></span>
</div>
```

All necessary code:

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions" type="AGS\OptionField\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions" />
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select">
        <plugin name="Ags_CategoryCustomAttribute_select" sortOrder="10" type="AGS\OptionField\Block\Magento\Catalog\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**CustomOptions.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace AGS\OptionField\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;


use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductOptions\ConfigInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\Product\Options\Price as ProductOptionsPrice;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Modal;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Container;
use Magento\Ui\Component\DynamicRows;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Checkbox;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\ActionDelete;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Number;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface;


class CustomOptions extends \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomOptions
{
    /**#@+
     * Field values
     * 
     */
    const FIELD_LINK_NAME = 'link';

    /**
     * Get config for grid for "select" types
     * 
     * @param int $sortOrder
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getSelectTypeGridConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'addButtonLabel' => __('Add Value'),
                        'componentType' => DynamicRows::NAME,
                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows',
                        'additionalClasses' => 'admin__field-wide',
                        'deleteProperty' => static::FIELD_IS_DELETE,
                        'deleteValue' => '1',
                        'renderDefaultRecord' => false,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                'record' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record',
                                'positionProvider' => static::FIELD_SORT_ORDER_NAME,
                                'isTemplate' => true,
                                'is_collection' => true,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'children' => [
                        static::FIELD_TITLE_NAME => $this->getTitleFieldConfig(10),
                        static::FIELD_PRICE_NAME => $this->getPriceFieldConfig(20),
                        static::FIELD_PRICE_TYPE_NAME => $this->getPriceTypeFieldConfig(30, ['fit' => true]),
                        static::FIELD_SKU_NAME => $this->getSkuFieldConfig(40),
                        static::FIELD_SORT_ORDER_NAME => $this->getPositionFieldConfig(50),
                        static::FIELD_LINK_NAME => $this->getLinkFieldConfig(55),
                        static::FIELD_IS_DELETE => $this->getIsDeleteFieldConfig(60)
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get config for "Inventory" fields
     * 
     * @param $sortOrder 
     * @param array $options
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getLinkFieldConfig($sortOrder, array $options = [])
    {
        return array_replace_recursive(
            [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('Link'),
                            'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                            'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                            'dataScope' => static::FIELD_LINK_NAME,
                            'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                            'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                            'validation' => [
                                'required-entry' => true
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            $options
        );
    }
}
```

**Select.php**

```
<?php
namespace AGS\OptionField\Block\Magento\Catalog\Product\View\Options\Type;

class Select extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\AbstractOptions
{
    /**
     * Return html for control element
     *
     * @return string
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function afterGetValuesHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select $subject)
    {
        $_option = $subject->getOption();
        $configValue = $subject->getProduct()->getPreconfiguredValues()->getData('options/' . $_option->getId());
        $store = $subject->getProduct()->getStore();

        $subject->setSkipJsReloadPrice(1);
        // Remove inline prototype onclick and onchange events

        if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN ||
            $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE
        ) {
            $require = $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required' : '';
            $extraParams = '';
            $select = $subject->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select'
            )->setData(
                [
                    'id' => 'select_' . $_option->getId(),
                    'class' => $require . ' product-custom-option admin__control-select'
                ]
            );
            if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_DROP_DOWN) {
//                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getid() . ']')->addOption('', __('-- Please Select --'));
            } else {
                $select->setName('options[' . $_option->getid() . '][]');
                $select->setClass('multiselect admin__control-multiselect' . $require . ' product-custom-option');
            }
            foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
                $priceStr = $subject->_formatPrice(
                    [
                        'is_percent' => $_value->getPriceType() == 'percent',
                        'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                    ],
                    false
                );
                $select->addOption(
                    $_value->getOptionTypeId(),
                    $_value->getTitle() . ' ' . strip_tags($priceStr) . '',
                    ['price' => $subject->pricingHelper->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false)]
                );
            }
            if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_MULTIPLE) {
                $extraParams = ' multiple="multiple"';
            }
            if (!$subject->getSkipJsReloadPrice()) {
                $extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()"';
            }
            $extraParams .= ' data-selector="' . $select->getName() . '"';
            $select->setExtraParams($extraParams);

            if ($configValue) {
                $select->setValue($configValue);
            }

            return $select->getHtml();
        }

        if ($_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO ||
            $_option->getType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX
        ) {
            $selectHtml = '<div class="options-list nested" id="options-' . $_option->getId() . '-list">';
            $require = $_option->getIsRequire() ? ' required' : '';
            $arraySign = '';
            switch ($_option->getType()) {
                case \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_RADIO:
                    $type = 'radio';
                    $class = 'radio admin__control-radio test';
                    if (!$_option->getIsRequire()) {
                        $selectHtml .= '<div class="field choice admin__field admin__field-option">' .
                            '<input type="radio" id="test_options_' .
                            $_option->getId() .
                            '" class="' .
                            $class .
                            ' product-custom-option" name="options[' .
                            $_option->getId() .
                            ']"' .
                            ' data-selector="options[' . $_option->getId() . ']"' .
                            ($subject->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"') .
                            ' value="" checked="checked" /><label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_' .
                            $_option->getId() .
                            '"><span>' .
                            __('None') . '</span></label></div>';
                    }
                    break;
                case \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option::OPTION_TYPE_CHECKBOX:
                    $type = 'checkbox';
                    $class = 'checkbox admin__control-checkbox';
                    $arraySign = '[]';
                    break;
            }
            $count = 1;
            foreach ($_option->getValues() as $_value) {
                $count++;

                $priceStr = $subject->_formatPrice(
                    [
                        'is_percent' => $_value->getPriceType() == 'percent',
                        'pricing_value' => $_value->getPrice($_value->getPriceType() == 'percent'),
                    ]
                );

                $htmlValue = $_value->getOptionTypeId();
                if ($arraySign) {
                    $checked = is_array($configValue) && in_array($htmlValue, $configValue) ? 'checked' : '';
                } else {
                    $checked = $configValue == $htmlValue ? 'checked' : '';
                }

                $dataSelector = 'options[' . $_option->getId() . ']';
                if ($arraySign) {
                    $dataSelector .= '[' . $htmlValue . ']';
                }

                $dataLink = 'data-link="' . $_value->getLink() . '"';

                $selectHtml .= '<div class="field choice admin__field admin__field-option' .
                    $require .
                    '">' .
                    '<input data-link="' .
                    $dataLink . 
                    '" type="' .
                    $type .
                    '" class="' .
                    $class .
                    ' ' .
                    $require .
                    ' product-custom-option"' .
                    ($subject->getSkipJsReloadPrice() ? '' : ' onclick="opConfig.reloadPrice()"') .
                    ' name="options[' .
                    $_option->getId() .
                    ']' .
                    $arraySign .
                    '" id="options_' .
                    $_option->getId() .
                    '_' .
                    $count .
                    '" value="' .
                    $htmlValue .
                    '" ' .
                    $checked .
                    ' data-selector="' . $dataSelector . '"' .
                    ' price="' .
                    $subject->pricingHelper->currencyByStore($_value->getPrice(true), $store, false) .
                    '" />' .
                    '<label class="label admin__field-label" for="options_' .
                    $_option->getId() .
                    '_' .
                    $count .
                    '"><span>' .
                    $_value->getTitle() .
                    '</span> ' .
                    $priceStr .
                    '</label>';
                $selectHtml .= '</div>';
            }
            $selectHtml .= '</div>';

            return $selectHtml;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

**UPD**

Ok, I have found how to get info from this field and paste for options with type radio and checkbox.

My new question is, how can I check if the field is empty and hide `data-link=""`? And also, can I put Radio Checkbox for product options for choosing checked options on the product page?